# How to prevent multi qt console windows opening from ipython notebook

Tags: python, qt, ipython

In Ipython Notebook, if I run

```
%qtconsole
```

then a new qtconsole window appears.

How do I check whether or not a qt console already exists, to prevent multiple windows from opening?

Comment: If you see qt console; don't type `%qtconsole`?

Comment: I have a script that automatically opens the qtconsole and I run it many times. On subsequent runs, I'd prefer it not to run the qtconsole

Comment: do not open the console inside the script at all. Open the console manually and then run the script multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following trick:

```
try:
  console_is_running
except NameError:
  console_is_running = True
  %qtconsole
```

It will work well in notebook